# Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16 to the 15 allowed. How to refactor and reduce the complexity

Tags: java, sonarqube, apache-poi

How can I reduce the complexity of the bellow piece of code? I am getting this error in SonarQube:

> High :Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16
> to the 15 allowed.

```
private void changeFontColorInMinusValue(final AssetContent content) throws IOException {
      if (!Objects.isNull(content)){
        try (final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(content.getTemporaryFile());
             final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
             final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
          final CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
          XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
          font.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.RED.getIndex());
          style.setFont(font);
          for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); ++sheetIndex) {
            final XSSFSheet sheetAt = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            for (Row row : sheetAt) {
              Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
              while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if(cell.getCellType() == NUMERIC && cell.getNumericCellValue() < 0){
                    cell.setCellStyle(style);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          workbook.write(byteStream);
          content.setTemporaryFile(AssetContentUtils.createAssetContentTempFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.toByteArray())));
          content.setContentLength(byteStream.size());
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, but I'd probably move the inner `for` loop to a method of its own, something like `private void applyStyleToNegativeNumbersInSheet(CellStyle style, XSSFSheet sheet)` which has the added benefit of explaining what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

The methods should have better names but this should help with the refactoring.

```
private void changeFontColorInMinusValue(final AssetContent content) throws IOException {
        if (Objects.isNull(content)) return;
        try (final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(content.getTemporaryFile());
             final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
             final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            final CellStyle style = getCellStyle(workbook);
            for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); ++sheetIndex) {
                cellLoop(style, workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex));
            }
            workbook.write(byteStream);
            content.setTemporaryFile(AssetContentUtils.createAssetContentTempFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.toByteArray())));
            content.setContentLength(byteStream.size());
        }
    }

    private CellStyle getCellStyle(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        final CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.RED.getIndex());
        style.setFont(font);
        return style;
    }

    private void cellLoop(CellStyle style, XSSFSheet sheetAt) {
        for (Row row : sheetAt) {
            setCellStyle(style, row.cellIterator());
        }
    }

    private void setCellStyle(CellStyle style, Iterator<Cell> cellIterator) {
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if (cell.getCellType() == NUMERIC && cell.getNumericCellValue() < 0) cell.setCellStyle(style);
        }
    }
```